# What wrong in my code with Laravel 4.2 Eloquent ORM

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

When the below is executed:

```
$user = User::where('email','=',$email)->take(1)->get();
Auth::login($user);
```

I get the error:

```
Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Auth\Guard::login() must implement interface Illuminate\Auth\UserInterface, instance of Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection given ...
```

I have tried changing this to:

```
$user = User::where('email','=',$email)->take(1)->get();
$userid = $user->id;
$user=User::find($userid);
Auth::login($user);
```

But then I get the error:

```
Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::$id
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when you are using `get()` it returns collection of users means you may have multiple records though you have used `take(1)` but that number may be different so it always returns collections, so you can`t directy access property of object.

you can use `first()` to get single user object.

try this

```
$user = User::where('email','=',$email)->first();
Auth::login($user);
```

**EDIT**

you can use `firstOrFail()` instead of `first()` here, as if you don't get specified user `firstOrFail()` through an error.

Comment: it's better to use ``firstOrFail()`` here